# Django Email Backend Failing when DEBUG = False

Tags: django, email, django-settings, django-email

Has anyone experienced this issue where when DEBUG = True your applications can't send emails?

I'm trying to set up a password reset email and a contact form and both work fine in development and in production as long as DEBUG = False, but as soon as it equals True the email backend breaks (this is especially frustrating because I can't use DEBUG to find the issue).

My email config looks as follows:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@programaticlearning.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'CorrectPassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Can you share error logs/ exception that you are receiving

Comment: And share your view where the mail is sent